# Start Chromium as a single frame (no borders/gui)?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, gui, chromium

Is there a way to start Chromium (running Ubuntu latest) in a frame-only mode ? Without borders & the gui?

Tried CLI switches found there :

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

But `chromium-browser --window-position=10,10 --window-size=200,200 --app`does not do anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up to use [Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit).

Answer (score 2):

Is kiosk mode what you're after?

```
--kiosk {URL}
```

This will start chromium in fullscreen, but won't give you access to the address bar or allow switching back to normal mode. (You can leave {URL} blank if need be)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to be able to display 4 gui-less chromes on the same desktop, kiosk seems to be only for fullscreen, and window-size & window-position does not (seem to) work with it unfortunately.

Comment: There is an app called Split Screen [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eachfleknamlcepmplpdghagngjfjkin) which might be what you're looking for, but it only appears to do 2 frames at the moment.